# how to manage IP currency boards with C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I`d like to create a software in Windows Forms, where client can enter buying and selling prices for currency pairs and after clicking "Apply" button, this information must be shown on currency board.

interface would look like that one: https://ibb.co/Ctm4QNN

here is the pic of IP Board: https://ibb.co/0Gx4TjM

Print Servers are used to manage these IP boards. here is the link of the device, which is used to create Print Servers: 
https://www.tp-link.com/us/download/TL-PS110P.html

I have found .NET classes for print servers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printserver?view=netframework-4.7.2

can I use this class to achieve my goal? please, give me an advice to complete this task.  Thank you...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow )  Well you should have at least one board for testing - then install it in your PC (seems like it imitate TCP IP printer) then use 
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing?view=netframework-4.7.2  .... Then if you will have more specific code based questions - ask it here

Comment: Do you have the manual for the display board. When you do manage to interface  the display to your network you will need to know the protocol required to communicate with the board. Without knowing full details of how to communicate with the board it is not possible to give you an answer as to whether or not the class will be suitable.

Comment: this board is using rs232 protocol